# Generate random background image based on random number

Tags: javascript, css, random, document.write

Thought this would work but can't see where I'm going wrong. Just doesn't output the generated number and instead defaults to 0. The variable isn't updating.

Want to have a random image display as background, so I've created 5 images named bg-x.jpg.

Then generated a random number between 1 and 5 stored in `var imgNumber`

Then use `document.write` to print out a style on the page with that `imgNumber` in place of the file URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var imgNumber = 0;
function randomImage(imgNumber){
    var imgNumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    console.log('Random number is ' + imgNumber);
}
window.onload = randomImage;
document.write('<style type="text/css"> body{background-image:url("images/bg/bg-' + imgNumber +'.jpg");}</style>');
</script>
```

Console works fine and shows a random number so I can only assume I've gone wrong here?

```
document.write('<style type="text/css"> body{background-image:url("images/bg/bg-' + imgNumber +'.jpg");}</style>');
```

Comment: you have used local variable imgNumber in function so remove var of imgNumber inside function .
This is problem of function scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think all you need to do is replace:

```
var imgNumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```

With

```
imgNumber = 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
```

Inside your function, a new variable called imgNumber gets created and assigned, and the outer one isn't changed at all.

Edit: Try the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function randomImage(){
    return 1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
}
document.write('<style type="text/css"> body{background-image:url("images/bg/bg-' + randomImage() + '.jpg");}</style>');
</script>
```

You don't even need a function, the following would work too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<style type="text/css"> body{background-image:url("images/bg/bg-' + (1 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)) + '.jpg");}</style>');
</script>
```

Comment: Tried that but I think it must be an issue with global/local variables? The initialised variable is 0. I am only getting 0 so that var is not being updated.